# Java: ArrayList with suggested phrases for an auto-complete combobox

Tags: java, swing, combobox

I have a method which returns an `ArrayList` of phrases to be used as the user types characters into a combobox. These phrases would ideally show up in a drop-down menu.

The method is in a class of its own called `PhraseList`.

I have a GUI class which contains a combobox. How do I go about capturing what the user types in and then get this list of phrases to pop-up in a dropdown menu?

Comment: @EI756 are you heard about AutoComplete(d) JComboBox and JTextField

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract this/these Char(s) typed into JComboBox or JTextField, by implements [Document](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#document) and with [AttributeSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/AttributeSet.html),

Then you can determine for continious Chars sequence (I think that only for continious), startWith Char(s), contains Char(s),

Excelent example [AutoComplete JComboBox and JTextField](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/AutocompleteComboBox.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you'll need to register a [`DocumentListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html). For more information, see [How to Write a Document Listener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html).